# Rowwise subset of a DataFrame based on index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, subset

I have two DataFrames with the same kind of index (userid) but neither is a subset of the other. I want to remove all rows from the smaller that do not appear in the larger. I was under the impression that this was the intended use of the loc function but it actually adds rows.

```
Largedf.shape
Out[2]: (7341253, 39)

Smalldf.shape
Out[3]: (588939, 2)

Smalldf = Smalldf.loc[Largedf.index]

Smalldf.shape
Out[5]: (7341253, 2)

Largedf.shape
Out[6]: (7341253, 39)
```

There are several users in Smalldf that are not in Largedf so I had expected it to get smaller. Is there a better method to do this? Note that the rows are not sorted in anyway and the only what I have to keep track is with the index.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `isin`?

```
Smalldf = Smalldf[Smalldf.index.isin(Largedf.index))]
```

Comment: This is not a bug, see my comments here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7690. ``loc`` acts like a ``reindex`` when presented with a slice/index-like.